# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' not working after clean build

Tags: swift

swift code is not working after clean build.

how can i rewrite this simple code?

```
if let name: String = String(cString: (interface?.ifa_name)!), name == "utun0" {
                    print("Ipfound")
                    ipFound = true;
                }
```

i put image for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: Post code as text and not as an image. And there is no point in using `if let ...` for a method/constructor that does _not_ return an optional value. Furthermore, you can't first `let` declare variable and then try to assign a value to it.

Comment: add code, not pictures of code!  I'm trying to help here, and instead of copying your code, I'm typing it

Comment: Yes, please edit your question to include your (formatted) code, not pictures of code. I had to re-type your code in order to suggest a fix.

Comment: i am so sorry for adding image.... won't happen again... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if let` construct is used for "conditional binding" of an optional. The thing you are trying to assign to `name` (the function result) is not optional - instead, the value you are passing to `String(cString:,name:)` is optional.

You should rewrite your code to something like this:

```
if let interfaceName = interface?.ifa_name {
    let name = String(cString: interfaceName)
    if name == "utun0" {
       print("Ipfound")
       ipFound = true
    } else {
       print("name != Ipfound")
    }
} else {
    print("interface or interface.ifa_name is nil")
}
```

In that code I'm using optional binding to try to get a non-nil value from `interface?.ifa_name`.

If you use `!` "force unwrap" operator as you were trying to do, your code would crash if `interface` is nil, or if interface.ifa_name is nil.

### Edit:

Another way you could handle this, that would look closer to your original code, would be to use `map()` on the `Optional`:

```
if let name: String = interface?.ifa_name.map ({ String(cString: $0)}),
     name == "utun0" }
{
    print("Ipfound")
    ipFound = true;
}
```

The form of `map()` that works on an Optional takes an Optional as input. If that optional is nil, it returns nil. If the optional is not nil, the result returned by `map()` is the result of applying your closure to the unwrapped optional.

---